# How to escape square brackets in URLs

Tags: url, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a set of records from Solr where `field[@name='url']` can have the following format:

```
http://url/blabla/blabla.aspx?sv=[keyword%20keyword,%201]
```

My understanding is that the square brackets denote an array syntax and I would like to use XSLT to remove the square brackets from all URLs.

I am using an Open URL resolver, which does not currently handle those characters well. The best option would be to strip the square brackets from all URLs before such resources are mediated by the Open URL resolver.

There are cases where I have multiple occurrences of square brackets per URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested both solutions as recommended by Martin and Michael. The Url sent to the OpenURL consists of an ID and the actual URL, as follows:

```
  <openurl><xsl:value-of select="concat(field[@name='id'],'/', field[@name='url'])" /><openurl>
```

I have first employed fn:replace, as follows:

```
  <openurl><xsl:value-of select="concat(field[@name='id'],'/', replace(field[@name='url'], '\[\]', ''))" /><openurl>
```

then

```
<openurl><xsl:value-of select="concat(field[@name='id'],'/', iri-to-uri(field[@name='url']))" /></openurl>
```

Looking at the XML, the url still shows square brackets. Rather perplexed, I have then performed few some extra tests. Eventually, I have tried to use fn:encode-for-uri and the square brackets got replaced with an escape sequence in the form %xx. However, the final URl as mediated by the OpenUrl gets somehow re-formatted and the square brackets came up again. I am currently investigating the issue.

Thanks indeed,

I.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the identity transformation template and

```
<xsl:template match="field[@name='url']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\[\]', '')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

you have an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet that removes the brackets.

Comment: thanks indeed, very useuful. +1 for you and Michael, see my post for additional info.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to strip the square brackets, rather than escaping them? My instinct would be to use the function [`iri-to-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-iri-to-uri), which will percent-encode them:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-iri-to-uri

Comment: thanks indeed, very good advice. See my post for additional info